# How can I set up Retrospect on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, 64-bit, rpm

**Problem**

Retrospect is a backup system that my organization uses, but I can not find support for my Ubuntu 12.10 64bit desktop.

**What I have tried** (but did not work)

1. download the Redhat version and attempt to convert to deb

   ```
   wget http://download.dantz.com/archives/Linux_Client-7_6_100.rpm
   sudo alien Linux_Client-7_6_100.rpm
   ```
2. The Restrospect user forum has [this thread](http://forums.dantz.com/showpost.php?pid/143296/), which provides an i386 .deb file for installing Retrospect

**Question**

Is there a way to install this on my system?

Answer (score 2):

The i386 Debian package file should be able to be "forcefully" installed on an amd64 system via

```
dpkg -i --force-architecture
```

This will probably leave other issues lingering before the application can be used; the package probably depends on other libraries, specifically the i386 versions of these.

This is addressed in Debian, and therefore Ubuntu, by the [multiarch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) project. This enables a system to have the same libraries compiled for different architectures installed simultaneously. However, perhaps the package you are referring to does not have any problematic external package dependencies, and then you won't need these multiarch libraries (the forum post linked below kind of suggests this is the case).

How to continue from this point depends on the packages internal dependencies and layout. [This Ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8556279&postcount=3) seems to handle the exact situation of installing Retrospect on 64-bit Ubuntu, opting for

1. `alien` conversion from RPM to Debian package format
2. manually changing the `i386` string to `amd64` in the `debian/control` file
3. rebuilding the package.

I propose that step 2 should not be needed with the `--force-architecture` switch to `dpkg`, but if you do some experimenting, you will probably see how it works in practice.

Note that the forum post lists the packages `libstdc++6` and `libc6-i386` as prerequisites for Retrospect (this is where multiarch might be needed, but the person in the forum post seems to have managed without).